# How can I require my python script's argument to be a float in a range using argparse?

Tags: python, range, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'd like to use `argparse` on Python 2.7 to require that one of my script's parameters be between the range of 0.0 and 1.0.  Does `argparse.add_argument()` support this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `type` parameter to `add_argument` just needs to be a callable object that takes a string and returns a converted value. You can write a wrapper around `float` that checks its value and raises an error if it is out of range.

```
def restricted_float(x):
    try:
        x = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%r not a floating-point literal" % (x,))

    if x < 0.0 or x > 1.0:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%r not in range [0.0, 1.0]"%(x,))
    return x

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--arg", type=restricted_float)
```

Comment: I was originally going to choose FJ's as the accepted answer, simply because I like the "cleanness" of it (obviously arguable), but the simplicity of this won me over, and I'm using it in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Note: `restricted_float` should probably be replaced by whatever it represents as it will be shown in error messages. For example, I used this pattern in a toy project [`geocodertools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocodertools) and called it `longitude` and `latitude`.

Comment: @Danijel What do you mean? There are a lot of different types you might want to define; `argparse` can't know about them all. This *is* how `argparse` supports converting the string argument to whatever value you want.

Comment: I was expecting that `float` would be supported as `int` is with regards to `range`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Danijel A range of floats wouldn't be terribly useful. What's the next float after `0.5`? `0.6`, or `0.51`, or `0.501`, or...? While technically discrete, `float` isn't enumerable in any useful way.

Comment: An interval type that *only* supported inclusion, rather than enumeration, might be useful, but Python doesn't provide one.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I was thinking about a from-to range of floats, not individual values.

Answer (score 32):

Here is a method that uses the `choices` parameter to [`add_argument`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument), with a custom class that is considered "equal" to any float within the specified range:

```
import argparse

class Range(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.start <= other <= self.end

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=float, choices=[Range(0.0, 1.0)])
```

Comment: I like this one because it leaves the exception raising to argparse. Thanks!

Comment: One suggestion: have your `Range` class implement the `__contains__` method; then you can say `choices=Range(0.0, 1.0)` instead of wrapping it in a list.

Comment: The `__contains__`-approach gives `ValueError: length of metavar tuple does not match nargs` using Python 3.4. Otherwise it works well and I implemented `__repr__` to return `'{0}-{1}'.format(self.start, self.end)` for prettier help text as well.

Comment: Andrew's answer combined with @RickardSjogren comment gives a great result. Thanks!

Comment: Even with `__contains__` redefined, in Python 3.5.2 I get: `TypeError: 'Range' object is not iterable`
if I don't put it in a single-element list.
Solved redefining:
`def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return self
        else:
            raise IndexError()`

Comment: I tried using @PJ_Finnegan `__getitem__` addition, but it did not work in python 3.6.5. I still get `ValueError: length of metavar tuple does not match nargs`

Answer (score 8):

Adding **str** makes that the boundaries are visuable in the help.

```py
import argparse

class Range(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.start <= other <= self.end

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.__eq__(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{0},{1}]'.format(self.start, self.end)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=float, choices=Range(0.0, 1.0))
parser.add_argument('--bar', type=float, choices=[Range(0.0, 1.0), Range(2.0,3.0)])
```

Comment: For me the argparse error message seems to show the class's repr so I just changed your `__str__` method to `__repr__` to get a nice error message.

Answer (score 2):

The argparse.add_argument call expects an iterable as 'choices' parameter. So what about adding the iterable property to the Range class above. So both scenarios could be used:

```
import argparse

class Range(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.start <= other <= self.end

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return self.__eq__(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=float, choices=Range(0.0, 1.0))
parser.add_argument('--bar', type=float, choices=[Range(0.0, 1.0), Range(2.0,3.0)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would also like to in-/exclude the boundaries of the float range(s), I have extended the codings of above as follows:

```
from typing import Generator
import re
import argparse


class Range(object):
    
    def __init__(self, scope: str):
        r = re.compile(
            r'^([\[\]]) *([-+]?(?:(?:\d*\.\d+)|(?:\d+\.?))(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?) *'
            r', *([-+]?(?:(?:\d*\.\d+)|(?:\d+\.?))(?:[Ee][+-]?\d+)?) *([\[\]])$'
        )
        try:
            i = [j for j in re.findall(r, scope)[0]]
            self.__start, self.__end = float(i[1]), float(i[2])
            if self.__start >= self.__end:
                raise ArithmeticError
        except (IndexError, ArithmeticError):
            raise SyntaxError("An error occurred with the range provided!")
        self.__st = '{}{{}},{{}}{}'.format(i[0], i[3])
        self.__lamba = "lambda start, end, item: start {0} item {1} end".format(
            {'[': '<=', ']': '<'}[i[0]],
            {']': '<=', '[': '<'}[i[3]]
        )    
    def __eq__(self, item: float) -> bool: return eval(self.__lamba)(
        self.__start,
        self.__end,
        item
    )
    def __contains__(self, item: float) -> bool: return self.__eq__(item)
    def __iter__(self) -> Generator[object, None, None]: yield self
    def __str__(self) -> str: return self.__st.format(self.__start, self.__end)
    def __repr__(self) -> str: return self.__str__()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=float, choices=Range('[0., 1.0['))
parser.add_argument('--bar', type=float, choices=[Range(']0., 1.0['), Range(']2.0E0, 3.0e0]')])
```